# Building intranet with MVC, EntityFramework, AngularJS and Breezejs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, angularjs, breeze

As a learning project, i want to make a rather simple intranet project (login/out, create new users, projects etc) with some new libraries/frameworks,

But i am unsure as to how they all work together and what is needed.

For example, what would the best approach to build the above. I am thinking;
* .Net MVC4
* AngularJS
* BreezeJS
* EntityFramework with code first
* WebAPI/ServiceStack

Am i missing some components or are there to many?

n00b question - i know :)

Comment: And also; would razor views make sence in such a structure?

Comment: It doesnt matter but if you want to have full control on your html, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will all boil down to your personal preference on what tools to use.

You need MVVM on your views? I would probably use Knockout.js. You want an easy integrated CSS+JS for your UI with a cool user experience? I'd probably use Twitter Bootstrap.

Are you more versed on using noSQL or document based DB? I'd probably use MongoDB instead of EF.

Do you need service oriented architecture? Are there other systems needed to be interconnected regardless of the framework used? (Java <--> .NET) Then yes, you can use Web API for RESTful web services. If not, I don't see doing SOA as a part of your initial project.

Again, it's a matter of taste, skillset, requirements when it comes to the tools to be used.